# final Runnable refreshTicker = new Runnable() { public void run() { initialize();}; initialize(); } };

Tags: powermock

How to mock Runnable here using PowerMock.... here initialize () calls some two other methods.
Can you please clarify how this can be done? searched for almost 2days..

Answer (score 0):

Please try these steps:

1. Use the @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) annotation at the class-level of the test case.
2. Use the @PrepareForTest(ClassThatCreatesTheNewInstance.class) annotation at the class-level of the test case.
3. Use PowerMock.createMock(NewInstanceClass.class) to create a mock object of the class that should be constructed (let's call it mockObject).
4. Use PowerMock.expectNew(NewInstanceClass.class).andReturn(mockObject) to expect a new construction of an object of type NewInstanceClass.class but instead return the mock object.
5. Use PowerMock.replay(mockObject, NewInstanceClass.class) to change the mock object and class to replay mode, alternatively use the PowerMock.replayAll() method.
6. Use PowerMock.verify(mockObject, NewInstanceClass.class) to change the mock object and class to verify mode, alternatively use the PowerMock.verifyAll() method.

Reference:  https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor